# Cannot create instance of custom class

Tags: c++, g++

I have created classes Point and Vector. I am now trying to instantiate them, but g++ doesn't like anything other than a pointer; I can not create an actual variable. This is the only thing I have gotten to actually compile (ATM, Point and Vector are empty except for a public constructor that defines public X and Y variables):

```
#include "point.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Point* p = new typename Point::Point(3, 3);
    Vector* v = new typename Vector::Vector(2, -4);
    Point* p2 = new typename Point::Point(p->X - v->X, p->Y - v->Y);
    std::cout << "Point p:  (" << p->X << "," << p->Y << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector v: (" << v->X << "," << v->Y << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Point p2: (" << p2->X << "," << p2->Y << ")" << std::endl;

}
```

How come I have to create a pointer, and not a variable?

Comment: Show the statement that lead to error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it without pointers ([live demo](http://ideone.com/XRGTa8)):

```
#include "point.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Point p(3, 3);
    Vector v(2, -4);
    Point p2(p.X - v.X, p.Y - v.Y);
    std::cout << "Point p:  (" << p.X << "," << p.Y << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Vector v: (" << v.X << "," << v.Y << ")\n";
    std::cout << "Point p2: (" << p2.X << "," << p2.Y << ")\n";
}
```

Also, you can actually create custom output formatters for your types by defining `operator<<`, to simply printing ([live demo](http://ideone.com/aHSXiG)):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Point const& p)
{
    return os << '(' << p.X << ',' << p.Y << ')';
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Vector const& v)
{
    return os << '(' << v.X << ',' << v.Y << ')';
}

int main() {
    Point p(3, 3);
    Vector v(2, -4);
    Point p2(p.X - v.X, p.Y - v.Y);
    std::cout << "Point p:  " << p << '\n';
    std::cout << "Vector v: " << v << '\n';
    std::cout << "Point p2: " << p2 << '\n';
}
```